# Bassline Harmony

Tags: harmony, electric-bass-guitar

Compare guitar 2 and bass in the song tab here- [GnR - Nightrain](https://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/guns-n-roses-nightrain-bass-tab-s19645t3).

If you look at the notes played by bass relative to the guitar in verses 1 and 2, you can see instances of Major 6th, Minor 7th, Major 2nd etc.
Im wondering did the artist(bassist) arbitrarily thought to choose these notes or is it more of an example of a moving bassline- one that moves away from the root note to other intervals and returning back to the root?

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two parts that are not printed together is difficult and the fact that it’s TAB and not standard notation makes it even harder, at least for me. I did give the song a listen though and based on what I heard I would say the “interesting” intervals are all incidental, based on the fact that both players are playing independent linear parts. Those intervals just zip right by and what we hear is them grooving independently over the same chords, it works for me!